# Does skip_deploy_on_missing_secrets work in static web app pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-static-web-app

I would like to only build my static web app and not deploy it. I saw there is a env setting "skip_deploy_on_missing_secrets' but after setting that in the pipeline it just gets ignored and the pipeline fails with error saying the deployment token is not set. How exactly should I use this env setting? Does it actually work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much info on the internet about this parameter. However, at least Dapr docs suggest that it should work, and I doubt they'd put it in their docs if it didn't ([here](https://docs.dapr.io/contributing/docs-contrib/maintainer-guide/)).

However, I had problems getting it working as well.

One thing to notice there is that Dapr docs actually show a GitHub Action, and they work a little bit differently than Azure CICD YAML Pipelines, which I was using.

Finally I stumbled upon [this comment on a similar issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/679#issuecomment-1008449473) which hints that this magic undocumented parameter should be ***passed as an environment variable***. I was passing it as an `input`. Maybe GitHubActions forward these params to envs automatically?

So I tried setting it as ENV and it worked!

```
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: ...blahblahblah
      ....
      #skip_deploy_on_missing_secrets: true
      # ABOVE: this one is documented in few places, but it's expected to be a ENV var!
      #see https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/679
    env:
      SKIP_DEPLOY_ON_MISSING_SECRETS: true
```